# how to reset current form in a mutil step forms using a service to preserve data

Tags: angularjs, forms, angular-services

I created a multistep form using ng switch and 3 forms , in order to preserve the data over the forms I created one service using factory method.But I'm trying to create a reset button and I want to clear the data in all fields in current displayed form keeping the data in other forms which should be reflected in model created by factory.I tried to use setpristine over the form but model is not getting updated .
please help and check below js bin link
http://jsbin.com/raxorewuma/edit?html,css,js,output

```
  angular.module('bankAppOnline', [])
                          .controller('CustomerCtrl', function ($scope) {
                            $scope.step = 1;

                            $scope.advance = function () {
                              $scope.step++;
                            }
                             $scope.previous = function () {

                              $scope.step--;
                            }

                          })
                          .controller('firstformCtrl', function ($scope, Customer) {
                            $scope.customer = Customer.get();
                          $scope.reset = function() {


                                $scope.firstform.$setPristine();
                                //$scope.customer = Customer.get();
                            }  
                          })
                          .controller('secondformCtrl', function ($scope, Customer) {
                            $scope.customer = Customer.get();
                            console.log( $scope.customer );
                          })
                            .controller('thirdformCtrl', function ($scope, Customer) {
                            $scope.customer = Customer.get();
                            console.log( $scope.customer );
                          })
                          .factory('Customer', function () {
                            var customer = {
                              firstname: "",
                              lastname: "",
                              age:"",
                              city:"",
                              profession:"",    
                              mobile:"" ,
                             pan:"",
                             income:"", 
                             company:"",
                             designation:"",
                             profession:"",
                             address:"",
                             pin:"",
                             accountType:"" ,
                             fdCheck:"",
                             creditCardCheck:""
                            };

                            return {
                              get: function () {
                                return customer;
                              }
                            }
                          })

                          .controller('DebugCtrl', function ($scope, Customer) {
                            $scope.customer = Customer.get();
                          });// Empty JS for your own code to be here
```

Comment: Is it your intention that in calling `reset()` the data fields of the customer object will be cleared in some way? (i.e. the firstForm will be blank)

Comment: @AndrewTomlinson yes , I can  clear the fields through angular.copy({}) but customer factory data is not getting updated yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $setPristine function clears the dirty class from the input element only. It does not reset the data. To do that, you must explicitly reset each data element in the form that corresponds to the data in the customer model, see my code for an example:
Option 1 (transparent approach):

```
  .controller('firstformCtrl', function ($scope, Customer) {
    $scope.customer = Customer.get();
    $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.firstform.$setPristine();

        // The elements to reset for the first form. 
        // You'll have to do this foreach controller's reset function.
        var restore = {
            "firstname": "",
            "lastname": "",
            "age": "",
            "city": "",
            "profession": "",
            "mobile": ""
        };
        angular.extend($scope.customer, restore);

    };  
  })
```

Option 2 (encapulation):

```
.factory('Customer', function () {
    var customer = {
        firstname: "",
        lastname: "",
        age:"",
        city:"",
        profession:"",    
        mobile:"" ,
        pan:"",
        income:"", 
        company:"",
        designation:"",
        profession:"",
        address:"",
        pin:"",
        accountType:"" ,
        fdCheck:"",
        creditCardCheck:""
    };

    return {
        get: function () {
            return customer;
        },

        reset: function(keys){
            angular.forEach(keys, function(val) {
                customer[val] = ""
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Now replace the reset function with the following for the first form. Each additional form will call  the Customer.reset function with the appropriate array of keys as the argument.

```
$scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.firstform.$setPristine();

    // The elements to reset for the first form. 
    // You'll have to do this foreach controller's reset function.
    var valsToReset = [
        "firstname",
        "lastname",
        "age",
        "city",
        "profession",
        "mobile"
    ];
    Customer.reset(valsToReset);
};
```

Comment: what is resets in extend function @dlporter98

Comment: thanks man thats working correctly !! Can you please explain why it dint work when I do angular.copy ??

Comment: where are you using copy(), I cannot find the code to comment on it.

Comment: Oops i deleted it instead of extend i used copy to empty objects but didnt work

Answer (score 2):

The form object that is maintained behind the scenes by AngularJS is separate from your Customer object. Setting preistine on the form will not automatically clear data fields in model object that's behind the HTML form. The bottom line is that you will have to supply the code to clear this data. I might included this a functionality of the Customer within the factory, because Customer is basically operating as a singleton. Then call these customer functions from inside the `reset()` function on each from controller.

```
.factory('Customer', function () {
        var customer = {
          firstname: "",
          lastname: "",
          age:"",
          city:"",
          profession:"",    
          mobile:"" ,
         pan:"",
         income:"", 
         company:"",
         designation:"",
         profession:"",
         address:"",
         pin:"",
         accountType:"" ,
         fdCheck:"",
         creditCardCheck:""
        };

        return {
          get: function () {
            return customer;
          },

          clearFirst: function() {
              //clear all the properties that are 
              //a part of the first form
              customer.firstname = "";
              customer.lastname = "";
              //....continue clearing
          },

          clearSecond: function() {
              //clear all the properties that are 
              //a part of the second form
          },

          clearThird: function() {
              //clear all the properties that are 
              //a part of the third form
          }
        }
```

})

Comment: thanks for the answer.dlporter98 answer is working fine and doing the job perfectly. Can you let me know which way should I follow??

Comment: incorporating the reset functions in the costumer object is good practice. I would create one reset function on the customer object that takes an array of keys to clear. That would make more flexible than creating individual clear methods.

Comment: I absolutely agree with @dlporter98 and his solution is awesome. If you study the AngularJS form object some, there is probably also a nice way to create a function that's part of the Customer object which accepts an Angular form as the input parameter.  The function would then loop through the fields in the form and clear the corresponding Customer fields. So, instead of having three separate functions, you would have one function something like `clearFields( someForm )` and would simply pass the instance of your firstform, secondform, etc. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks all , I learnt a lot about angular with our discussion